# WCSF reading materials

Tags: .net, wcsf

Please suggests good articles which helps in grasping concepts of wcsf architecture, usage with a possible demonstration.

Regards,
Justin Samuel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do any of these links help?

- http://www.pnpguidance.net/Post/WCSFApplicationArchitectureTutorialsLayeringDesignPatterns.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264518.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The http://www.pnpguidance.net/Post/WCSFApplicationArchitectureTutorialsLayeringDesignPatterns.aspx was excellent tutorial for learning WCSF. It helped me understand the concept to a great extend.

Also few more suggestions from my side.
1) The videos at the bottom of the previous link is extremely beneficial, worth downloading. David Hayden has done an extremely great job on this.

2) Download the guidance pattern for WCSF Feb 2008 and it comes with help and samples which are beneficial.

All the best ALL!

Also remember practicing such things is the best way to learn stuffs quickly!!

Regards,
Justin Samuel.